# Google Maps v3 InfoBox Add Event Listener

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google Map (v3) with 20 markers. I have a single InfoBox instance that gets populated with a div that includes the text to fill the box as innerHTML.

I want to be able to click on the infobox and navigate away to a different page, but I can't get the infobox, or the div inside it to respond to a click event.

I've tried adding an event listener, and I've tried adding a domListener, but I can't get either to work.

Here are some snippets from my code

```
//setting up the infobox

    var infobox = new InfoBox({
           disableAutoPan: true
          ,isHidden:false
          ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10, -10)
          ,closeBoxURL: ""
          ,pane: "mapPane"
          ,enableEventPropagation: true
        });

    //setting up the div

    var boxText1 = document.createElement("div");
        boxText1.id = "boxText1";
        boxText1.className = "labelText";
        boxText1.innerHTML = title1;//this is created earlier

    //the marker event listener - the marker and coordinates are also set up earlier
       google.maps.event.addListener(_marker1, 'click', function() { 
       infobox.content_ = boxText1;
       infobox.position_ = mkLatLng1;
       infobox.open(map);
    });

      //so far everything ok. When the user clicks the marker the infobox pops up - but.....

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxText1,'click',function(){ alert('clicked!') });//doesn't work
```

I've tried a variety of other options, but they're all shots in the dark. What's the best way to listen for a click event on an infobox?

Thanks

Comment: does the little cross close the infobox?

Comment: Your infobox's text can contain html right? So you could make a div in it, and listen for clicks on that div.

Comment: There is no little cross. Are you thinking of the info window?

Comment: The infobox does have a div inside and I have been trying to listen for clicks on it, but with no luck.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of the info window. D'oh!

Comment: Funnily enough when I comment out the closeBoxURL the close box does appear - and I can't click it! More confusion :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved. In the infobox options you have to ensure that you have

```
pane: "floatPane"
```

and NOT

```
pane: "mapPane"
```

as I had it. Works fine now.

Interestingly the Google Docs say

```
Set the pane to "mapPane" if the InfoBox is being used as a map label.
```

What they don't say is that you can't use this option if you want the map label to be clickable.

Comment: In my case, I had to switch to `mapPane` from `floatPane`